# Creating new Emulator with Android 10. Getting Unexpected feature list: MultiDisplay VulkanNullOptionalStrings

Tags: android, android-emulator

Creating a new Android Emulator device using Android10 sdk. The emulator creation process is success. While opening the Emulator device, getting the Emulator exception as

`Emulator: Unexpected feature list: MultiDisplay VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUV420888toNV21 YUVCache` in EventLog.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when updated Android Studio to 3.6 and when launching the application on my newly created Emulator of API Level 29

I solved it by -

```
Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Platforms - updated the required API Level (in my case API Level 29)
```

Then -

```
Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools - updated all the previously checked tools
```